# In Powershell, how do I sort a Collections.Generic.List of DirectoryInfo?

Tags: list, powershell, sorting, unique, directoryinfo

I want a list of the unique directories that contain a file matching subjectPattern.
I can get the list, but to get the unique directories, I need to sort it. But because the list is
of type Collections.Generic.List[DirectoryInfo], I'm having trouble finding a working API.

```
function Get-Containers([Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$subjectPattern) {
    #NOTE: The class for directories is System.IO.DirectoryInfo, the class for files is System.IO.FileInfo
    $fatList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]    
    $result = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
    foreach ($leafName in (get-childitem -recurse -force -path . -include $subjectPattern)) {
        $fatList += (Get-Item $leafName).Directory
    }
    #Get-Unique only works on sorted collections, Sort-Object won't work without a Property,
    # but "FullName" is not a property of Collections.Generic.List
    # Furthermore, Sort() is not a method of [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
    $result = ($fatList.Sort() | Get-Unique )
    return $result
}
```

How do I sort, then get unique items in Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] ?

Comment: The proper way to append elements to a list is through its `Add()` method -> `fatList.Add((Get-Item $leafName).Directory)`. `+=` is inefficient for adding collection members. You can group your objects and then sort --> `$fatList | Group FullName |% { $_.Group[0] } | Sort Name`. I don't know if that is your goal. If your leaf item does not have a `Directory` property, you will have null values in your list that aren't visible in your output.

Comment: Is it important to sort in-place for some reason? Is it important that you specifically use a generic list?

Comment: No, none of the details of this function were important to me, except that it return a collection of unique DirectorInfo. So no need to sort in-place, or be a List instead of a HashObject. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your inline comments:

> [...] `Sort-Object` won't work without a Property, but "FullName" is not a property of Collections.Generic.List

That's fine, we're not sorting multiple *lists*, we're sorting multiple `DirectoryInfo` objects that happen to be contained in a single list.

The big question is: **Do you need to sort in-place?**

Sorting "in-place" means re-arranging the objects *inside* the list, so that the list itself retains the new sort order *and* its identity. This is usually less resource-intensive, but slightly complicated in PowerShell.

The alternative is to enumerate the items in the list, sort them *externally* and then (optionally) wrapping the re-ordered items in a *new* list - much easier to implement, but at a resource cost (which you may or may not notice depending on the size of the collection and the complexity of the comparison).

## Sorting in-place

In order to sort multiple `DirectoryInfo` objects, we need a way to instruct the `List[DirectoryInfo].Sort()` method on how to compare the objects to each other and determine which comes before or after the other in the sort order.

Looking at the `Sort()` method overloads gives us a clue:

```
PS ~> $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
PS ~> $list.Sort

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Sort()
void Sort(System.Collections.Generic.IComparer[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] comparer)
void Sort(int index, int count, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] comparer)
void Sort(System.Comparison[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] comparison)
```

So we need something that implements the generic interface [`IComparer[T]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1).

Using PowerShell's ability to define new types at runtime using the `class` keyword, we can do:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.IO

class DirectoryInfoComparer : IComparer[DirectoryInfo]
{
    [string]$PropertyName
    [bool]$Descending = $false

    DirectoryInfoComparer([string]$property)
    {
        $this.PropertyName = $property
    }

    DirectoryInfoComparer([string]$property, [bool]$descending)
    {
        $this.PropertyName = $property
        $this.Descending = $descending
    }

    [int]Compare([DirectoryInfo]$a, [DirectoryInfo]$b)
    {
        $res = if($a.$($this.PropertyName) -eq $b.$($this.PropertyName))
        {
            0
        }
        elseif($a.$($this.PropertyName) -lt $b.$($this.PropertyName))
        {
            -1
        }
        else
        {
            1
        }

        if($this.Descending){
            $res *= -1
        }

        return $res 
    }
}
```

... and now we can sort the list in-place based on a property name, just like with `Sort-Object`:

```
# Create a list
$list = [List[DirectoryInfo]]::new()

# Add directories in non-sorted order
mkdir c,a,b -Force |ForEach-Object { $list.Add($_) }

# Instantiate a comparer based on the `FullName` property
$fullNameComparer = [DirectoryInfoComparer]::new("FullName")

# Now sort the list
$list.Sort($fullNameComparer)

# Observe that items are now sorted based on FullName value
$list.FullName
```

---

## Sort externally

Now that we know the trials we must go through to sort a generic collection in-place, let's review the process of sorting the collection externally:

```
$sorted = $list |Sort-Object FullName
```

If we need the resulting (now sorted) collection to also be of type `[List[Directory]]`, we can either clear and re-populate the original list:

```
$list.Clear()
$sorted |ForEach-Object {$list.Add($_)}
```

... or we can create a new `[List[DirectoryInfo]]` instance:

```
$list = [List[DirectoryInfo]]::new([DirectoryInfo[]]$sorted)
```

---

## How about a `SortedSet[DirectoryInfo]`?

As [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65962763/edit), a "set" might be a better collection type for the purpose of only storing *unique* items.

The `HashSet[T]` type is an *unordered* set, but .NET also comes with a [`SortedSet[T]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) - *and you won't believe what it requires to implement the sort order* - that's right, an `IComparer[T]`! :-)

In this case, we'll want to inject the comparer into the constructor when we create the set:

```
# Once again, we need an IComparer[DirectoryInfo] instance
$comparer = [DirectoryInfoComparer]::new("FullName")

# Then we create the set, injecting our custom comparer
$set = [System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new($comparer)

# Now let's add a bunch of directories in completely jumbled order
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |Select -First 10 |Sort {Get-Random} |ForEach-Object {
    # The Add() method emits a boolean indicating whether the item 
    # is unique or already exists in the set, hence the [void] cast
    [void]$set.Add($_)
}

# Once again, observe that enumerating the set emits the items sorted
$set.FullName
```

---

As you can see, there are multiple options available, with varying degrees of complexity and performance characteristics. It's not entirely clear from your question *why* you're using a generic list or why you insist on sorting it using `List.Sort()`, so my recommendation would be to test them all out and see what works best for you

Answer (score 2):

Trying changing:

```
$fatList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
```

to a HashSet, which allows for only unique values.

```
$fatList = New-Object Collections.Generic.Hashset[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
```

and commenting out:

```
#$result = ($fatList.Sort() | Get-Unique )
```

@AdminOfThings is correct, use the .Add() method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-5.0. Also, are you sure you want Directory, instead of DirectoryName?

Edit: I just realized I didn't fully answer the question. Once the HashSet variable is set with unordered items (default behavior), pipe it to a Sort-Object cmdlet.