# Are non-concurrent collections safe inside concurrent collections?

Tags: .net, powershell, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm looking to start implementing some concurrent functions in a project that I'm working on. I recently discovered the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace that I am planning to leverage.

The object that I use to track the overall state of the actions is essentially a dictionary with some nested custom objects. My thought is that as long as the highest level collection is configured to be concurrent/thread safe, it doesn't matter if the nested collections are, since the data will be locked by the higher level collection.

Is this the correct assumption?

For example, would something in PowerShell like the following be safe to use?

```
[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[[String], [MyCustomClass]]]::new()
```

Additionally, I have some custom class that extend HashSet to avoid duplicates. Since System.Collections. Concurrent don't have a HashSet class, what is the recommended way to get similar functionality but concurrently?

Comment: No that's absolutely not correct, it only locks access to the dictionary, not to any of the returned value's properties and methods. I'm not entirely sure how you thought it could do so. But if each key/value pair is only ever accessed by one thread (even if other pairs are accessed by other threads) then it is safe

Comment: I think I may have explained poorly. The nested class is what is essentially a private class and it only accessed through methods on the parent class which holds the dictionary. In that case is this a fine implementation since the dictionary would require threads to wait to access the nested class until they can look it up when the dictionary becomes available to them?

Comment: Again, as I said, it depends on whether different threads access the same key/value. If yes then there is nothing to stop another thread doing something not thread-safe with your private object. If not then it would be safe. Which of those is true in your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My thought is that as long as the highest level collection is configured to be concurrent/thread safe, it doesn't matter if the nested collections are, since the data will be locked by the higher level collection.
>
> Is this the correct assumption?

No, that's **not** a safe assumption.

Let's say you create a concurrent dictionary containing a bunch of regular hashtables:

```sh
using namespace System.Collections.Concurrent

# Create thread-safe dictionary
$rootDict = [ConcurrentDictionary[string,hashtable]]::new()
```

- `$rootDict` is now thread-safe - more than one thread cannot concurrently modify the `'A'` entry by overwriting the reference to the hashtable
- Any inner hashtable that we add to `$rootDict` is **NOT** thread-safe - it'll still just be a regular hashtable

In PowerShell 7 this can be observed when using `ForEach-Object -Parallel` to operate on such a data structure:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Concurrent

# Create thread-safe dictionary
$rootDict = [ConcurrentDictionary[string,hashtable]]::new()

1..100 |ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  # We need a reference to our safe top-level dictionary
  $dict = $using:rootDict

  # ... and we need a key
  $rootKey = $_ % 2 -eq 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'

  # Thread-safe acquisition of inner hashtable
  $innerDict = $dict.GetOrAdd($rootKey, {param($key) return @{}})

  # Add a bit of jitter for realism
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Minimum 50 -Maximum 250)

  # Update inner hashtable entry
  $innerDict['Counter'] += 1
} -ThrottleLimit 10

# Are these really the results we're expecting...? 
$rootDict['odd','even']
```

If the inner hashtable entries were thread-safe to update concurrently, you would expect both counters at `50`, but I get results like this on my laptop:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Counter                        46
Counter                        43
```

We can see multiple updates to the inner 'Counter' entry are lost in the process, presumably due to concurrent updates.

---

To test this hypothesis, let's do the same experiment, but with another concurrent dictionary type instead of the hashtable:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Concurrent

# Create thread-safe dictionary with a thread-safe item type
$rootDict = [ConcurrentDictionary[string,ConcurrentDictionary[string,int]]]::new()

1..100 |ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  # We need a reference to our safe top-level dictionary
  $dict = $using:rootDict

  # ... and we need a key
  $rootKey = $_ % 2 -eq 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'

  # Thread-safe acquisition of inner hashtable
  $innerDict = $dict.GetOrAdd($rootKey, {param($key) return @{}})

  # Add a bit of jitter for realism
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Minimum 50 -Maximum 250)

  # Thread-safe update of inner dictionary
  [void]$innerDict.AddOrUpdate('Counter', {param($key) return 1}, {param($key,$value) return $value + 1})
} -ThrottleLimit 10

# These should be the exact results we're expecting! 
$rootDict['odd','even']
```

Now I get:

```
Key     Value
---     -----
Counter    50
Counter    50
```

---

> I have some custom class that extend HashSet to avoid duplicates. Since System.Collections. Concurrent don't have a HashSet class, what is the recommended way to get similar functionality but concurrently?

Instead of explicitly inheriting from `HashSet`, I strongly recommend *wrapping* a `HashSet` and then guard all the methods you want to expose to the user with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` - this way you achieve thread-safety without needlessly sacrificing read access performance.

Here, against using `[int]` as the sample date type:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Threading

class ConcurrentSet
{
    hidden [ReaderWriterLockSlim]
    $_lock

    hidden [HashSet[int]]
    $_set

    ConcurrentSet()
    {
        $this._set = [HashSet[int]]::new()
        $this._lock = [System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim]::new()
    }

    [bool]
    Add([int]$item)
    {
        # Any method that modifies the set should be guarded
        # by a WriteLock - guaranteeing exclusive update access
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.Add($item)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    IsSubsetOf([IEnumerable[int]]$other)
    {
        # For the read-only methods a read-lock will suffice
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.IsSubsetOf($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    # Repeat appropriate lock pattern for all [HashSet] methods you want to expose
}
```

You can make the wrapper more flexible by [wrapping a `HashSet<object>`](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/3df90728a09dd638beaae379b116d018) and controlling the behavior with a [custom comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960853/in-powershell-how-do-i-sort-a-collections-generic-list-of-directoryinfo/65968654#65968654)

Comment: Yeah I see your point. I was assuming the lock wouldn't be lifted until the action completes on the nested key/value pair which was a poor assumption.

Comment: @Efie regarding custom concurrent set types, see update to my answer

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much for the additional example